# How to match number of arguments in constructor and deploy()

Tags: solidity, hardhat-deploy, constructor

This is my constructor

```
constructor (uint256 _initialSupply) {
        ownerOfContract = msg.sender;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }
```

But when I deploy the contract, it gives me the following error:

> {
> reason: 'missing argument:  in Contract constructor',
> code: 'MISSING_ARGUMENT',
> count: 0,
> expectedCount: 1
> }

Upon googling I came to know that constructor and deploy function should have same number of arguments when deploying through hardhat. But what should I pass in deploy()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Contract.deploy()`, you just need to pass the constructor parameters in the order they are declared in your contract, like this:

`Contract.deploy(initialSupply)`, or `Contract.deploy("100000000")`;

If your constructor looked like this: `constructor (uint256 _initialSupply, string tokenName)`

Then you would deploy it in hardhat like:

`Contract.deploy("100000000", "TokenA")`